# Python : Scraping through search based index pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

Here is my Python code for scraping through a real estate search page.
Unfortunately I can't figure out how to actually go through the search results index pages. I guess i have to pass a `params` in the `requests.get`, some query, but I can´t find what.

Module: Scanner

```
import requests


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

STARTPAGE='https://www.immotop.lu/de/search/'

class Request:
    """
    Make request to ImmotTop.lu


    """
    def __init__(self, page):
        self.page = page
        self.r = requests.get(self.page, allow_redirects=False, headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'})
        self.text =self.r.content
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.text, 'html.parser')

    @property
    def ItemLinks(self):
        """
        Gets a list of links on the index page
        """
        self.item_links1 = self.soup.find_all('a', href=True, attrs= Locators.OBJECT_LINK1)
        self.item_links2= self.soup.find_all('a', href=True)
        self.item_links= self.item_links1 + self.item_links2
        self.link_list = []
        for a in self.item_links:
            self.link_list.append(a['href'])
        return self.link_list
```

This module is imported in the main module which runs the whole program.So here is the part where I go through the index pages.

Module: Main

```
index = 1
while index < 10000:
    index_page = 'index' + str(index) + 'html'
    links_all = Scanner.Request(Scanner.STARTPAGE + index_page).ItemLinks
    links = list(dict.fromkeys(links_all))
    print(Locators.STARTPAGE + index_page)
    for link in links:
```

Afterwards the single pages are parsed to extract data to a SQL database. But after scanning `index1.html` to `index10000.html`, I only get about 12.000 entries in my SQL Table, whereas the Immotop page shows about 36.ooo results for sale and about 10.000 for rent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is incomplete, in the *Module: Main* is missing the body of the `for`-loop (and `i` not incremented?) and in both code snapshots there are some variables which are not referenced, `Locators.OBJECT_LINK1` and `Locators.STARTPAGE`.

Under the assumption that the search results of the web page are reliable then it could be an **integrity problem** of the urls, try to catch some strange status code of the "request"/response by modifying the constructor as follow

```
# 
if self.r.status_code == 200:
   pass    
elif self.r.status_code in range(200, 300):
       print('Status code {} return by {}'.format(self.r.status_code, self.page))
else:
    print('Error, Status code {} return by {}'.format(self.r.status_code, self.page))
```

Since you have to **scrape** a lot of web pages improve your scraping function `ItemLinks` to save computational power (and time!)

```
def ItemLinks(self)
   self.item_links2 = self.soup.find_all('a', href=True)
   # assumed that Locators.OBJECT_LINK1 is a dict
   self.item_links1 = [a for a in self.item_links2 if  Locators.OBJECT_LINK1.items() <= a.attrs.items()]

   return map(lambda a: a['href'], self.item_links1 + self.item_links2)
```

[As already mentioned above concatenating paths as strings can be dangerous and can give rise to integrity problem.]